Can I Create a JDBC Connection URL Using AWS Credential Profile?
I am trying to create a JDBC connection to Amazon Athena using AWS credentials stored in an AWS profile (either through InstanceProfileCredentialsProvider or ProfileCredentialsProvider). However, the connection works only when I explicitly include the user and password in the connection string.
I would like to know if it's possible to use AWS credential profiles in the JDBC connection URL to avoid hardcoding access credentials.
Working connection string (with user and password):
This works with hard-coded credentials:
jdbc:awsathena://AwsRegion=us-west-2;WorkGroup=primary;Catalog=AwsDataCatalog;
Database=default;S3OutputLocation=s3://fdsa-athena-data-store/;
User=AKIAEXAMPLE;Password=EXAMPLESECRET;

Non-working connection string (with profile):
I have tried the following connection string using both InstanceProfileCredentialsProvider and ProfileCredentialsProvider:
jdbc:awsathena://AwsRegion=us-west-2;WorkGroup=primary;Catalog=AwsDataCatalog;
Database=default;S3OutputLocation=s3://fdsa-athena-data-store/;AwsCredentialsProviderClass=com.simba.athena.amazonaws.auth.InstanceProfileCredentialsProvider;

or
jdbc:awsathena://AwsRegion=us-west-2;WorkGroup=primary;Catalog=AwsDataCatalog;
Database=default;S3OutputLocation=s3://fdsa-athena-data-store/;
AwsCredentialsProviderClass=com.simba.athena.amazonaws.auth.profile.ProfileCredentialsProvider;
AwsProfile=default;

Both attempts result in the following error:

java.sql.SQLException: Missing credentials error: Either UID/PWD or AwsCredentialsProviderClass must be provided.

How to establish a JDBC connection to Athena using AWS credential profiles without explicitly including the user and password in the connection URL?

Hey Richard. You need to specify the profile name in the JDBC connection string (for example: jdbc:awsathena://AwsRegion=us-west-2;Profile=xxx;). Why are you using AwsProfile? And can you confirm you're using the latest version of the driver?

Thank you for the response!
We are using the instance in an EC2 environment, and due to internal policies, we cannot use user and password for authentication. That's why we're attempting to use the instance profile for credentials management, specifically leveraging the InstanceProfileCredentialsProvider.
hasura/graphql-engine:v2.43.0
hasura/graphql-data-connector:v2.43.0

@RichardCamiloSaavedraConeo according to this documentation (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/athena/latest/ug/jdbc-v3-driver-instance-profile-credentials.html), the parameter name for passing instance profile credentials is "CredentialsProvider", and the alias is marked as deprecated. Are you using the 3.x driver?

I'm not entirely sure which version of the driver Hasura is using at the moment.
However, I was able to connect successfully from an EC2 instance using the following parameter:
AwsCredentialsProviderClass=com.simba.athena.amazonaws.auth.InstanceProfileCredentialsProvider
I haven't managed to connect from a local environment yet, while using the Profile parameter.
